# CRT Monitor Screen is Blurry for 15 minutes of starting the PC

Tags: display, crt

I have a CRT Monitor that was working properly, 
a day ago, we had a storm and I didn't notice that I didn't close the door properly (which has the PC next to it),

when I returned I checked if anything in the Room was wet, but nothing was wet at all (everything was just cold, I suspect humidity),

but then I opened the PC and noticed that the Monitor (it has holes in its outer-skeleton for some reason) is too blurry as if I had a bad eye vision, so I restarted and it got from 100% of bad to 90%, then I left it for like half an hour and it returned to normal but only 80% of the screen's top,

next day I opened it again and same problem, but this time it took less time to return normal (nearly 20 minutes),

also I would like to mention that I've kept using the **Degauss** functionality multiple times, I feel that it helps to speed up the process

Comment: Split the problem in two.  Can you try another monitor?  and does another monitor work?  That is half the problem (other half is the computer)

Comment: @John can't try another monitor, but noticed now that the monitor has a sound inside of it as if something's moving.

Comment: To add to John's comment - I wouldn't give this more than 20 minutes of testing. If another screen works, then put the old dear out to grass. A cheap 2nd hand LCD would save you the money in electricity bills inside 6 months.

Comment: "the monitor has a sound inside of it as if something's moving"   Coils for sweeping the beam across (horizontal sweep) and up/down (vertical sweep) have likely loosened and are vibrating and screwing up the sweep accuracy

Comment: BTW, holes are for ventilation. CRT's use vacuum-tube (valve) technology, with heated filaments.

Comment: Do I assume that the monitor will be fixed by itself while it is heating itself over the next days? I keep suspecting that the humidity is the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: I'd suspect some component just reached end of life, perhaps pushed over the last small cliff by the weather. I wouldn't expend any energy on diagnosing it, just hope your local recycling facility doesn't charge for 'dangerous' component disposal. It is a screen whose time has come & gone many years ago. It is currently costing you more in electricity bills than it is worth, unless you're actually using it to heat the room. Let it go to rest.